# How to design a 1-500MHz sine wave level detector to -90dBm?

Tags: rf, high-frequency, detector, noisefloor

I want to build a sine wave level detector that works for a single 1-500MHz sine wave in the range of -40dBm to -90dBm. This is a hobby project - so cost is not a big obstacle :-), but I want to stay below 2W and roughly matchbox sized.

My first attempt works well only down to -75dBm, so I need some help to design a better circuit to get to -90dBm. What is the best way to design a circuit to do this?

**BACKGROUND**

The first attempt at a design is here:

[image]

My signal chain is like this:

SMA > [ADG918](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADG918_919.pdf) (switch) -> [MAX2611](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2611.pdf) (LNA) -> MAX2611 (LNA) -> [AD8363](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8363.pdf) (level detector) -> A/D converter

The first switch can select a reference signal of a known amplitude for calibration. The two LNA’s have about 20dB gain each. Absolute accuracy is not important - it can all be calibrated away as long as the circuit is relatively stable.

Results from the first design:

[image: <graph>]

I know I am fighting 1/f noise and thermal noise, but what is a good design that can achieve measurements down to -90dBm?

**Update**

I know now that thermal noise puts the noise floor above the target for a 500 MHz wide band, so a different circuit is required (just as Andy aka explains in his answer below).

The system "knows" the frequency to measure and there is a fairly pure tone of that exact frequency in the system at -10dBm.

A perfect answer would point out example key parts and sketch out a rough block diagram.

Comment: Do you know what frequency you're trying to measure the power of? My first thought is to design a 1-500 MHz calibrated receiver, which would allow you to add more gain to the system without worrying about oscillations.

Comment: The circuit should be able to measure level of any frequency in the range - actually I want to go as low as possible, but not higher than 500 MHz.

Comment: Sure, but in that range, when you are trying to measure the power of a signal, do you know what frequency the signal is at?

Comment: Dave, yes there is a signal of the exact same frequency present in the system as well.

Answer (score 3):

Thermal noise for a bandwidth of 500MHz at 50 ohms is about 20 \$\mu\$V at 20degC. You can double check this with [this](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-noise.htm) calculator but the long hand method is: -

\$ V_n = \sqrt{4\cdot K_B\cdot T\cdot R\cdot \Delta F}\$

Where Kb is Boltzmann's constant, T is temperature, R is 50 ohms and \$\Delta F\$ is 500MHz

Anyway 20uV and 50 ohms gives a power of 8 pico watts and this is -81dBm.

You won't get -90dBm without making the circuit tuned to reject noise in areas you are not interested in. Or maybe consider some form of refridgeration?

Comment: Yes I realized that - now the question is: What is the best way to do this then?

Comment: @RolfOstergaard do you know the frequency of the sinewave you are interested in i.e. can you roughly band limit the range to reduce noise. If you don't know the frequency then maybe you can still band limit but sweep until you find it? How will you know when you find it if you don't know its frequency? I need more information to see if it's solvable.

Comment: There is a tone of the exact same frequency present in the system already. And the sweep method would work as all other pure tones are known to be at a lower amplitude.

Comment: @RolfOstergaard If you have a reference tone then I wouldn't hesitate to use "it" and a 90deg version to do I and Q demodulation via mixers - you'll generate two dc signals representing the in-phase and quadrature phase wrt to your reference (call them I and Q). Then it's \$\sqrt{I^2+Q^2}\$ to get the RMS of your unknown amplitude.

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea, but can you be more specific? Say the reference tone is -10dBm, where would you put the gain stages? Can you suggest a suitable mixer that will output okay? (mini-circuits etc. is okay)

Comment: Id probably look at analog devices first and see what the mixer spec suggests is the nominal amplitudes needed for best performance. This would tend to dictate how much front-end gain you need and how big your LO  signal(s) need to be .

Comment: So would you use a passive mixer like http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADL5350.pdf or an active mixer like http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8343.pdf ?

Comment: Unfortunately my phone line died about 6 hours ago so it maybe some time before I can answer that one Rolf

Comment: The first one appears to be only suitable for around 850MHz. I'm not 100% keen on the 2nd one either because the local oscillator signal is used to switch the input signal rather than it being a multiplication function but, I've used this technique before on very tiny signals with I and Q local oscillators and it worked great - not sure how the 2nd will cope with out of band signals that are harmonics of the local oscillator. I think the 2nd one is worth a try. You'll need two unless you know the phase relationship between reference signal and signal to be detected.

Comment: If I understand you correctly http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADL5391.pdf would be a better part then? This is a true multiplier supporting DC coupling. The varying input impedance does not look good however. Happy Newyear, All.

Comment: @RolfOstergaard Happy new year to you Rolf - that device looks really nice apart from needing 130mA supply. The AD8343 might work ok providing there are no other signals (harmonically related) that could upset things.

Comment: Thanks - so with 2x the AD8343 and a -10dBm differential LO drive - how low can the input level realistically be? Can you read that from the datasheet? Can this work all the way down to 500 Hz if I wanted?

Comment: I can't answer that Rolf I think you're going to have to try it and see. I've used synchronous demodulator up to a bandwidth of 1MHz ang managed to extract a signal in the tens of nano volts but I used clever auto zero techniques to counter dc voltage drift. The signal was slow moving but if it was moving too slow the auto balance got rid of it.

Comment: That fair enough - thanks for letting me know. As for trying something, this Linear part looks interesting as well (10mA). http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/5560f.pdf All provided I can find a simple way to do DC-500MHz single-ended to differential conversion...

Comment: For your solution to work I would need to create a 90 deg phase shifter that works over the whole frequency range - how would you do that? Or is there a way around that?

Comment: Rolf, here's another mixer that might work better: http://www.linear.com/product/LT5560. If you can manufacture a frequency that is "1kHz" higher or lower than your target frequency - you'd be able to down-convert to 1kHz and use a tight band-pass filter and amplitude detector to get the signal level - this is an alternative to creating a 90 deg phase shift. I think this technique may be better because then you'd be amplifying and detecting a LF frequency and dc errors wouldn't be a problem. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it looks like a good low power mixer. How would you do single-ended to differential conversion over 0.01-500MHz for the input?

Comment: Try figure 22 but as you need an amplifier before this I'd find one with diff outputs. Wideband transformers are possibly an option of course as min frequency is 1MHz.